# Hadamard (entrywise) product in the Magma computer algebra system

Tags: magma-cas

Is it possible to efficiently compute the Hadamard product (= entrywise product) of 2 matrices in MAGMA? I can't find anything in the documentation.

The best thing I can come up with is computing it directly with 2 nested for loops, but this is really slow.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#In_programming_languages) can help you, i.e. you can search for an "array multiplication" command in Magma.

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find such a command :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are the matrices? And what field? If you write your own function, I would imagine it's pretty efficient.

```
function HadProduct(A,B)
 return Matrix([[A[i,j]*B[i,j] : j in [1..Ncols(A)]] : i in [1..Ncols(A)]]);
end function;
```